# EOS Ram allocation

Tags: ram, ram-allocation

As the ram allocation model changed in Dawn 4.0, it looks like EOS token holders are not allocated any "free" ram, it has to be bought using EOS native tokens.

Question is, who owns the ram initially? Block Producer? ie Dapps developers buy ram from BP when EOSIO is launched?

Answer (score 1):

RAM is provided by the block producers; they own the hardware. When dapp developers or users require RAM, they need to stake EOS to be allocated that RAM. If they no longer need the RAM, they can unstake the EOS and get it back, from what I understand.

Comment: I think it was true on or before DAWN 3.0, since DAWN 4.0, RAM needs to be bought at market price (in EOS), so when you no longer need the allocated RAM, you may get back more or may get back less (in EOS) than your initial investment.

Comment: You're right, that makes this interesting. There's also a 1% fee and the fact that it can't be transferred to think about.

Comment: FYI, I think it is 0.5% to buy and 0.5% to sell so effectively 1% like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the RAM is not owned by anyone before somebody buys it. It is not owned by Block Producers or anyone else.

When you by RAM you stack EOS Coins. This is similar to say that you exchange RAM for EOS and vise versa. This happen in a closed system. i.e you only exchange RAM with EOS and you cannot exchange RAM with any other coin directly.

The bad thing I think about this is that the early EOS investors got 0 RAM. And some early investors, like me, feel bad about this. Because, we expected that once EOS is up-and-running we can any time start developing on it. But it turns out that we have to buy something additional.

Additionally, DApps developers (and I am one of them) is now not incentivised to develop for EOS because they have to buy EOS coins in addition to RAM for a considerable price. However, the price of RAM could go down, if a side-chain is established or if RAM could be added to the main-chain. But this is not enough from my point of view and the RAM model still needs more enhancements.

The good thing is that EOS will continue to evolve and it is designed to overcome any issue. And I hope the issues in the RAM model at Dawn 4.0 will be resolved in Dawn 5.0. Just like how Dawn 4.0 was better that Dawn 3.0.

Comment: I hear you. I am too very concerned about the "RAM Market" being a negative component for EOS as far as independent dApp developers are concerned. I am writing an article on Steem.It to explain what I understand from the perspective of a dApp architect. I have spoken and heard from Dan Larimer on various EOS related telegram channel and I think I understand his vision, attitude and it may or maynot jibe well with independent developers like us.  Stay tuned!